# Convert A String to List in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am a Prolog newbie and am stuck at parsing a string to a list. I have a string of the form. I want to read polynomial as String and convert it into String.
I want to convert the input String

```
2x^3 + x^2 - 4x^1 - 8
```

to

```
[[2,3], [1,2], [-4, 1], [-8, 0]]
```

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: no. just one variable on a polynomial named x by default

Comment: no. the user can enter the summands As he want.

Comment: please repeat i'm still waiting for your solution

Comment: Why a string? Your initial input looks very much like Prolog text. You simply need a dot at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is easily solved in two steps:

1. Lexical analysis / tokenizer: convert the string into a list of tokens that represent each of the possible elements of the expression: numbers, variable names and operators. The representations maybe, for instance, the terms `number(V)`, `vname(N)` and `op(Op)`; you may wish to use different terms for the additive operators that separate the monomials and for the exponent operator.
2. Syntactic analysis / parser: apply grammar rules to the list of tokens to identify monomials and convert them to the required representation. In this case each rule could have the form of a clause that inspects what appears at the beginning of the tokens list to find a monomial and convert it.

Sample rules could be

```
monom([number(N),vname(X),op(exp),number(E)|Ts],[[N,E]|Ms]) :-
  !, monom(Ts,Ms).
 monom([number(N),vname(X),op(+)|Ts],[[N,1]|Ms]) :-
  !, monom([op(+)|Ts],Ms).
```

Note that these rules do not check whether the variables have always the same name. Another issue is using the minus sign of a monomial. But I hope you will be able to cope with this.

Comment: Thanks, but i really don't understand what to do. Can you help me with a peace of code?

Comment: I assume you refer to the 1st step. A string is a list of characters, spaces are separators and otherwise ignored, a number (an unsigned integer) is a sequence of digits, a name is a single letter, an operator is one of `+`, `-`, or '^'. If you manage to build a list of characters for each number, name or operator you can then use `name/2` (check the manual) to get the corresponding atomic term and then you build a term as in my answer with it as the argument. It is easy: you will learn from writing it yourself.

Comment: please help :( i'm not understanding

Comment: 1st step: Write a predicate `tokens(Cs,Ts)` that from a list of chars `Cs` builds a list of tokens `Ts` as explained above. You need to know how to visit a list recursively for doing this and how to convert a string into a term whose name is that string (read the documentation of your Prolog system to find more on this;  try the  `atom_chars/2` or  `name/2` predefined predicates). If each number, name and operator is  written as a single char, each char corresponds to a token. You can start from this case.